# Sitecore search to support pdf files

Tags: solr, content-search

how to implement search to support pdf files? Is it possible with Sitecore 10 & Solr on azure pass?

Comment: What do you mean by search PDF files? Do you want to search through PRF content?

Comment: If yes - you can do it through the computed index field. There you can add logic for getting text from PDF and passing it to SOLR

Comment: Sitecore has OOTB mechanism to search content of media files: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-content-of-media-files.html. But PDF search works only for "selectable" pdf-files, not for "scanned" (sitecore uses PDFSharp nuget package). If you need to search also in "scanned" pdfs, you should setup Apache Tika, but I`m not sure if it is compatible with Azure. As a workaround you can implement your custom PDF content indexing by using Tesseract .Net wrapper (open source OCR, Tika uses it too) https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-samples